# Why does sequelize add the COUNT of each model I include together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I'm trying to get the information about a user and include all the reservation he has done as well as the total sales.

I'm trying to add a *before get* hook and include both reservations and sales. When I include just one of these it gets the `COUNT` right, but when I add both, it actually counts reservations and sales and adds them together for each one.

```
    get: [
      authenticate("jwt"),
      context => {
        context.params.sequelize = {
          include: [
            {
              association: "reservacion",
              required: false,
              attributes: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("reservacion.id")), "total_res"]]
            },
            {
              association: "venta",
              required: false,
              attributes: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("venta.id")), "ventas"]]
            }
          ]
        };
        return context;
      }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `DISTINCT` you should avoid the problem of accumulation of results

```
 get: [
      authenticate("jwt"),
      context => {
        context.params.sequelize = {
          include: [
            {
              association: "reservacion",
              required: false,
              attributes: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.fn("DISTINCT", Sequelize.col("reservacion.id")), "total_res"]]
            },
            {
              association: "venta",
              required: false,
              attributes: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.fn("DISTINCT", Sequelize.col("venta.id"))), "ventas"]]
            }
          ]
        };
        return context;
      }
    ],
```